# Is a space with symplectic form and compatible complex structure a unitary space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let's assume that:

$V$ is a real vector space,

$w:V\times V \to \Bbb R$ is a skew-symmetric form which non-degenerated (the last assumption means: $x\in V\ \&\ w(x,y)=0\ \forall y\in V\implies x=0$),

$J:V\to V$ is a complex structure on $V$, that is $J$ is linear and $J^2=-Id$,

$w$ and $J$ are compatible: $w(Jx,Jy)=w(x,y)$ for $x,y \in V$.

Is it then a function $\langle x,y\rangle=w(x,Jy)$ for $x,y \in V$ the inner product on $V$?

I want only to know if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is positive definite, because the other axioms of inner product are easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Counterexample: with respect to the standard basis of $V=\mathbb R^2$, let the matrix representations of $J$ and $w$ be $J=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$ and $W=J^T$. Then
$$w(Jx,Jy)=y^TJ^TWJx=y^TWx=w(x,y),$$
but
$$w(x,Jy)=y^TJ^TWx=y^T(J^T)^2x=-y^Tx$$
is the negative of the usual inner product.

Comment: @Alex It works. I define $w(u,v)=v^TWu$. Perhaps you adopt the convention that $w(u,v)=u^TWv$. In that case, take $W=J$ instead.

Comment: Yes, we have used another convention. Thanks for the counterexample.